# Real Analysis Question MVT or Rolle's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

I am taking a Introduction to Real Analysis course and I am having difficulty answering this question. The question reads:

"Let $f$ be twice differentiable function and $f''$ be continuous. Let 
$p(x) = \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}$ for $x$ not equal to $a$ and $p(a) = f'(a)$. 
Prove that $p'(a) = \frac{f''(a)}2$."

I believe proving this involves The Mean Value Theorem or Rolle's Theorem, but I am not positive.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The second order Taylor-Lagrange formula gives

$$f(x)=f(a)+(x-a)f'(a)+\frac{(x-a)^2}{2}f''(c_x)$$

with $c_x\in(a,x)$ or $(x,a)$.

$\implies$

$$p(x)=p(a)+\frac{x-a}{2}f''(c_x)$$

$\implies$

$$\frac{p(x)-p(a)}{x-a}=\frac{f''(c_x)}{2}$$

and when $x\to a$, we get

$$p'(a)=\frac{f''(a)}{2}$$ since $c_x\to a$ and $f''$ continuous at $a$.

Comment: Thank you for your help! My only question is how did you get from step three to step four?

Comment: @JohnSeibert by the definition of derivative  of $p$ at $x=a$ and by the fact that $a<c_x<x$ with squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Applying l'Hospital yields
$$ \lim_{x\to a} \frac{p(x)-p(a)}{x-a} = \lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a) - f'(a)(x-a)}{(x-a)^2} = \lim_{x\to a} \frac{f'(x) - f'(a)}{2(x-a)} = 2f''(a). $$
No need for $f''$ to be continuous at $a$.